# Access json content of http post request with Klein in python

Tags: python, klein-mvc

I have a simple http client in python that send the http post request like this:

```
import json
import urllib2
from collections import defaultdict as dd
data = dd(str)
req = urllib2.Request('http://myendpoint/test')
data["Input"] = "Hello World!"
response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(data))
```

On my server side with Flask, I can define a simple function

```
from flask import request
@app.route('/test', methods = ['POST'])
def test():
    output = dd()
    data = request.json
```

And the `data` on server will be the same dictionary as the `data` on the client side.

However, now I am moving to Klein, so the server code looks like this:

```
@app.route('/test', methods = ['POST'])
@inlineCallbacks
def test(request):
    output = dd()
    data = request.json <=== This doesn't work
```

and the request that's been used in Klein does not support the same function. I wonder is there a way to get the json in Klein in the same way I got it in Flask? Thank you for reading this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Asaik Klein doesn't give you direct access to the json data, however you can use this code to access it:

```
import json

@app.route('/test', methods = ['POST'])
@inlineCallbacks
def test(request):
    output = dd()
    data = json.loads(request.content.read())  # <=== This will work
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks you. I just don't know how to access the content (request.content.read())

Comment: I spend hours trying "request.args.get" which does not work as expected for some reason. Then I find this post by chance and now my problem get solved. Thank!!!!!!

Comment: @chanp, glad I could help :)

Comment: In python3 you need seem to need to decode bytes => str, e.g. `data = json.loads(request.content.read().decode('utf-8'))`